# is it possible to use expression (e.g.:{{i}}) inside onclick?

Tags: angular, syntax

I want to use expression inside onclick like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let student of studentList;let i=index;">
  <div id="studentDetail{{i}}">Details....</div>
  <div onclick="(function(){
    document.getElementById('studentDetail{{i}}').hidden=true;
  })"</div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use (click)=... as it needs to modify the .ts file, but it seems incorrect because it shows blank page, is it possible to use expression inside like this:

```
document.getElementById('studentDetail{{i}}').hidden=true;
```

?

Comment: *I don't want to use (click)=... as it needs to modify the .ts file*. Why? Can't you modify the *component* file? Also, you could explain more your situation... maybe there're another ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

This should be implement  like this ,

```
<div *ngFor="let student of studentList;let i=index;">
    <div *ngIf="!student.hidden">Details....</div>
    <div onclick="hideStudentDetail(student)"></div>
</div>
```

and in your component

```
hideStudentDetail(){
   student.hidden=true;
}
```